# When EVE shut down, how did Wall-E's electronics turn off?

Tags: wall-e

When EVE got the plant in Wall-E and shut down, everything in Wall-E's home turned off. How?

Comment: There's nothing in the script to explain it; https://imsdb.com/scripts/Wall-E.html

Comment: There's nothing in the [official novelisation](https://tinyurl.com/jzrdeken) that explains it *"He tapped her on the shoulder and held up the plant. EVE’s blue light immediately locked onto it. Her chest opened. WALL·E was shocked to see a tractor beam suddenly shoot from EVE’s chest and envelop the plant. The beam had pulled the plant into a compartment in EVE’s chest. Her panel doors slammed, and her system shut down altogether! Only a single green light remained pulsing on her chest."*

Comment: Is it possible she had been powering the places lights?

Comment: @Christopher - Wall-E turns on the lights. When she gets excited about the plant, the lights glow really brightly, suggesting that she's emitting electromagnetic energy

Comment: @Valorum then there's some way EVE turned off the power to Wall-E'e electronics when she shut down since the switch is on. After she shut down, Wall-E's electronics should be running off home power, unless EVE shut that off as well at shutdown.

Comment: @user144247 - I presume she blew the fuse. For the record, there's nothing relevant in either of the commentaries (crew/director) other than a brief mention of her fingers giving the bulb power and something about magnets.